# Copy columns from a matrix to another matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix say ABC which has 60 rows and 120 columns.
Depending on another matrix X which is a 120 entry long array I would like to populate another matrix as follows:

`if X(i)=1` column i is added to the matrix ABC_Copy.
`if X(i)=0` column i is skipped the loop continues.

As it is obvious i would iterate from 1 to 120 which is the size of `S` representing the 120 columns in `ABC`.

How can we implement this in matlab without iterating entirely and placing each value individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [logical arrays for indexing](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) in Matlab:

```
ABC_Copy = ABC(:, X==1);
```

Comment: Or if X is a calculated value, use `abs(X-1)<eps` to avoid floating point errors. Or `find(X)`.

Comment: Thanks.
Also if I want to create a 3D matrix from say 3 2D matrices how do I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by creating a 3-D matrix from 3 2-D matrices. If it's not related to this question, you should consider posting a new question about that.

Comment: @3lectrologos I found the answer here thanks :)
http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/28949